# I need to animate container to shake in a 3 by 3 gridview on tapped

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been really stuck figuring out how to animate individual containers to do a little shake when pressed in a 3x3 grid view in flutter :(

I need all containers in grid to always be **squares**

Comment: Can you add that you've tried yet.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Result**

[image: result]

If you like to handle cut-off container, use stack. Or handle it diff way.
**Main Widget**

```dart
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  get color =>
      Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(33.0),
              child: GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 3,

                ///* play with spaces
                mainAxisSpacing: 33,
                crossAxisSpacing: 33,
                children: [
                  ...List.generate(
                    9,
                    (index) => AnimatedGridContainer(
                      key: UniqueKey(),
                      color: color,
                      itemID: index,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**GridItem**

```
class AnimatedGridContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final int itemID;
  final Color color;

  const AnimatedGridContainer({
    Key? key,
    required this.itemID,
    required this.color,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _AnimatedGridContainerState createState() => _AnimatedGridContainerState();
}

class _AnimatedGridContainerState extends State<AnimatedGridContainer> {
  double degree = 0;

  ///* play with degreea and Duration
  shake() async {
    setState(() {
      degree = 30;
    });
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      setState(() {
        degree = -30;
      });
    });
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      setState(() {
        degree = 0;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: shake,
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        transformAlignment: Alignment.center,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
        color: widget.color,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(pi * degree / 180),
        child: Text(
          "${widget.itemID}",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 44),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```